# inverse Laplace transform for the function $ \frac{\sqrt{a+be^{-sp}+s}}{c}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I am trying to find the inverse Laplace transform for the  function
$$ \frac{\sqrt{a+be^{-sp}+s}}{c}$$
where $a,b,c,p $ are positive constant, and it seems impossible for me to find the answer.  Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to find it with the Inverse-Laplace transfrom formula or with table?

Comment: yes, step by step solution would be helpful. Either way I need the exact function coming out of inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: If you make a bounty of at least $100$ I will try to find a solution as hard as I can. Please don't think I'm greedy or anything like this, if you want everything step by step that takes time.  Not only the math, the explanation too.

Comment: How did you even get to that problem? Was it in a textbook?

Comment: No, its a  come up while taking a Laplace transform of pde.

Comment: Do you *have* to calculate the pde with the laplace transform? Which pde is it?

Comment: No, I dont have to calculate the pde but to reduction one dimension and then do some estimate on it. its a reaction diffusion type pde.

Comment: And what kind of solution do you expect? With the exponential and linear term under a square root it's going to be a little difficult...

Comment: I seriously dont know. yes it is difficult.

Comment: It is probably going to be a real integral, that you can not simplifie... Are you aware of that?

Comment: are you talking about cauch p.v integral?